# Getting position of element inside of listview asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, listview

I have a asp.net Listview. I want to be able to get the Position of one item. How do i accomplish this. I have already tried. Jquery.Position and jquery offset. They both have an incorrect top and left. Thanks for any help

Comment: can you post the code?  when you use Jquery.position what does it return vs what is should return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just used the mouse coordination on the page and that worked for me.
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position